# Get xls file mime type using php

Tags: php, mime-types, xls

I have `xls` file (From ms ecxel -> save as -> workbook excel 97-2003)

Then I upload this file on server using php, this is my code:

```
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']);
    echo $type;
```

result is: `application/msword`

Why this happened? As I know `xls` file type is `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: MIME type guessing is not an exact science.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your htaccess file on the root of your site:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel xls
```

This should allow apache to recognize xls file formats as a distinct format.